# Fetching remote XML file returns strange string

Tags: php, xml, fetch

I've got an weird problem.
When i go to the url in the browser, i get a nicely formatted XML structure in return.

```
<root>
 <contents/>
</root>
```

(fake data though)

But when i use cURL, file_get_contents (or even wget in Linux) i get some sort of serialized data wich is unusable for me.``

{"root:{"contents etc.

Anyone knows why and how to fix it?

Comment: can you post the code you're using?

Comment: are you able to provide the URL?

Answer (score 1):

It's JSON.
Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue of [Content Negotiation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Content_negotiation).

> To summarize how this works, when a user agent submits a request to a server, the user agent informs the server what media types it understands with ratings of how well it understands them. More precisely, the user agent provides an Accept HTTP header that lists acceptable media types and associated quality factors. The server is then able to supply the version of the resource that best fits the user agent's needs.

Your browser usually sends an Accept Header that requests text/html or something like that. The default of the server seems to be to serve json though. Make sure you send the appropriate Accept Header in the cURL request to tell the server how it should response to your request.

On a sidenote, if you are going to process the XML afterwards, you likely dont need cURL at all. All of the libxml based XML extensions can load from remote locations. And they can do so with a [custom HTTP stream context](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php).

Reference:

- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html
- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Answer (score 1):

The server is probably detecting the user agent and formatting results accordingly. In wget, add ‘--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20110619 Firefox/5.0’ option to make the server think you are coming from a browser. An alternative is to tell the server what content type you are expecting with the Accept Header.